# Position element absolute relative to 100% width parent

Tags: css, position, absolute

I'm trying to position a element absolute inside a parent which is set to position: relative, so far so good.

The issue is, that the parent is 100% width, and the absolute positioned element would then stick all the way to the right of the browser when right:0.

What I really want, is to position the element right, so it lines up with the wrapper of the page, which has width:1140px.

If I set the right to fx. 100px of the absolute element, it will of course have different outcomes on different resolutions.

A bit hard to explain, so I've made a jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/wxxezx0w/1/

```css
.navigation {
    width:500px;
    background:#def;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px 0;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.navigation ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
}
.navigation ul li {
    display:inline;
    padding-right:20px;
}
.grandParent {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
.parent {
    background: url('http://dummyimage.com/1800x1200/ccc/ccc') no-repeat 0 20%;
    background-size:cover;
    height:300px;
}
.child h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
.child .box {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    right: 0;
    background: #fed;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
    z-index: 10;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li>
            Home
        </li>
        <li>
            Page1
        </li>
        <li>
            Page2
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="grandParent">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
            <h1>Hello world</h1>
            <div class="box">Align me right, relative to navigation div</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SidOfc/wxxezx0w/3/) shows what you want, even when resized it will stay in the correct position.

I modified `.child .box` and added a `right: 50%;` and `margin-right: -250px;`

```
.child .box {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: -250px;
    background: #fed;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
    z-index: 10;
    display: block;
}
```

What this basically does is:

- `right: 50%;` - makes sure the element is always positioned `50%` from the right side of the screen.
- `margin-right: -250px;` - this is half of the width of your navigation, since your nav is centered it will be aligned the same as `right: calc(50% - (half-width-of-nav));` so the same calculation is made for positioning this element.

I hope this is understandable to you, if not let me know and I'll try to elaborate.

Also - if you can use CSS [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) ([compatibility table](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)) you could remove the negative margin and just use `right: calc(50% - 250px);`

Also note that if you change the width of your nav you'll also have to update this too so it comes at a price but when you visually change your design you'll see that this is no longer positioned correctly and all you'll have to do is modify the value.

Good luck!

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I wanted! It makes good sense too, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.navigation {
    width:500px;
    background:#def;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px 0;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.navigation ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
}
.navigation ul li {
    display:inline;
    padding-right:20px;
}
.grandParent {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
.parent {
    background: url('http://dummyimage.com/1800x1200/ccc/ccc') no-repeat 0 20%;
    background-size:cover;
    height:300px;
}
.child h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
.child < .box {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    right: 0;
    background: #fed;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
    z-index: 10;
    display: block;
}
```

Note that I've changed the parental relationship in your CSS adding `>` which means first child of, such as:     .`child < .box {}`

If you set a whitespace between one tag and another in CSS means that the first one contains the second, and in this case is true, but also exist a parental relationship.

Here the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wxxezx0w/2/

Comment: Your CSS operator `<` is invalid and will not work, it should be `>` and its use is explicitly for *direct* children. [See docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)

Comment: Looks like you arent selecting the box anylonger with this syntax

Comment: Sorry, but that is just doing the same thing as before, not really what I had in mind :)

Comment: What would be the top position of your div? I've positioned to the right, but just under the div that contains: Home, Page1 and Page2

Answer (score 0):

u have set

```
 .child .box { 
   bottom: -10px;
}
```

so it is outside the parent div.

Comment: Yes, Im not talking about the vertical alignment, but the horizontal :)
To clarify: It should align with the navigation horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

The 'box' has to be inside the 'child' element?

Otherwise you could make a wrapper with the same dimensions of the navigation, put inside the box and then position it on the bottom-right.

```css
.navigation {
     width:500px;
     background:#def;
     margin:0 auto;
     text-align:center;
     padding:5px 0;
     margin-bottom:10px;
    }
    .navigation ul {
     list-style-type:none;
     padding:0;
    }
    .navigation ul li {
     display:inline;
     padding-right:20px;
    }
    .grandParent {
     position:relative;
     width:100%;
    }
    .parent {
     background: url('http://dummyimage.com/1800x1200/ccc/ccc') no-repeat 0 20%;
     background-size:cover;
     height:300px;
    }
    .child h1 {
     position: absolute;
     top: 25%;
     left: 25%;
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 60px;
     font-weight: bold;
     width: 50%;
     text-align: center;
    }
    #box_wrapper{
     width: 500px;
     margin: auto;
     position: relative;
     height: 100%;
    }
    .box {
     float: right;
     margin: auto;
     background: #fed;
     padding: 10px 25px;
     color: #000;
     font-size: 20px;
     z-index: 10;
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
 <ul>
  <li>
   Home
  </li>
  <li>
   Page1
  </li>
  <li>
   Page2
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div class="grandParent">
 <div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
   <h1>Hello world</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="box_wrapper">
   <div class="box">Align me right, relative to navigation div</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use css calc and fixed width for absolute positioned element that will help.

```css
.navigation {
    width:500px;
    background:#def;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px 0;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.navigation ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
}
.navigation ul li {
    display:inline;
    padding-right:20px;
}
.grandParent {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
.parent {
    background: url('http://dummyimage.com/1800x1200/ccc/ccc') no-repeat 0 20%;
    background-size:cover;
    height:300px;
}
.child h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
.child .box {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    right: calc(50% - 250px);
    background: #fed;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
    z-index: 10;
    width:450px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li>
            Home
        </li>
        <li>
            Page1
        </li>
        <li>
            Page2
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="grandParent">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
            <h1>Hello world</h1>
            <div class="box">Align me right, relative to navigation div</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```